# repeated signal and slot for same widets in pyqt4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I have 10 lineedit widget that design by `qt-designer` and i define signal&slot in my code,
my problem is with repeating same signal&slot 10times in my code,
something like this:

```
self.ui.descCode_lineEdit_1.cursorPositionChanged.connect(lambda: self.Desc(1))
self.ui.Desc_lineEdit_1.editingFinished.connect(lambda: self.DescRate(1))

self.ui.descCode_lineEdit_2.cursorPositionChanged.connect(lambda: self.Desc(2))
self.ui.Desc_lineEdit_2.editingFinished.connect(lambda: self.DescRate(2))

...
self.ui.descCode_lineEdit_10.cursorPositionChanged.connect(lambda: self.Desc(10))
self.ui.Desc_lineEdit_10.editingFinished.connect(lambda: self.DescRate(10))
```

i write these with `getattr` :

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    getattr(self.ui, 'descCode_lineEdit_{}'.format(i)).cursorPositionChanged.connect(lambda: self.Desc(i))
    getattr(self.ui, 'Desc_lineEdit_{}'.format(i)).editingFinished.connect(lambda: self.DescRate(i))
```

but when run code, only 10th widget's signal&slot works fine, other fields nothing.
Any idea to how to fix this part of code and repeated same signals ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here lies within the lambda, and the i. Later on only the last value of i will be saved. Hence try it like this:

**Minimal *not working* example**:

```
>>> def test(a):
...     print a
... x = []
... for i in range(2):
...     x.append(lambda: test(i))
... x
14: [<function <lambda> at 0x027FBA30>, <function <lambda> at 0x027FBAF0>]
>>> x[0]()  # is supposed to print 0 not 1
1
>>> x[1]()
1
```

**Minimal working example**:

```
>>> def test(a):
...     print a
... x = []
... for i in range(2):
...     x.append((lambda x: (lambda:test(x)))(i) )
... x
16: [<function <lambda> at 0x027FBBF0>, <function <lambda> at 0x027FBBB0>]
>>> x[0]()
0
>>> x[1]()
1
```

**What is happening?**

In the second example, I have my outter `lambda` function return a function. The outter `lambda` function will be evaluated with the input `i` returning a function that has this `i` built into it. Hence the value of `i` is individually saved and things work as intended.

**Solution**

Hence your solution could look something like this:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    ...connect((lambda x:(lambda: self.Desc(x)))(i))
    ...connect((lambda x:(lambda: self.DescRate(x)))(i))
```

Cheers!

Comment: thx for your support, what is x in solution part ? i use it this way and error happend : for i in range(1, 18):
            getattr(self.ui, 'descCode_lineEdit_{}'.format(i)).cursorPositionChanged.connect(lambda i: (lambda: self.Desc(i)) (i))          error : TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @alireza.m Sorry, fixed it :) the outter one needs to be the `i` :) and make sure you get the parenthesis right!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to use a data structure.

```
fields = [QLineEdit() for x in range(10)]
for i in range(10):
   fields[i].cursorPositionChanged.connect(lambda: self.Desc(i+1))
   fields[i].editingFinished.connect(lambda:self.DescRate(i+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try for this code:-

```
for i in range(1,11):
   getattr('self.ui.descCode_lineEdit_'+format(i)+'.cursorPositionChanged.connect(lambda: self.Desc('+format(i)+'))')
   getattr('self.ui.Desc_lineEdit_'+format(i)+'.editingFinished.connect(lambda: self.DescRate('+format(i)+'))')
```

Comment: TypeError: getattr expected at least 2 arguments, got 1